DSum mistake in choosing the right database records with multiple criteria in 3 fields
In the following Google-sheets database, I cannot get the choice of correct records with multiple criteria in 3 fields.



Plant
Number
Field
Expire date




Oak
10
A
2034-11-01


Cherry
5
B
2026-04-01


Elm
20
A
2038-12-01


Maple
5
B
2025-11-01


Oak
30
B
2033-05-01


Pine
10
A
2025-12-31


Yew
5
B
2025-03-01


Yew
20
A
2028-06-01


Elm
3
A
2024-12-31



with this array



Plant
Field
Expire Date




Yew
A
<=2034-10-21



B




and this function
DSUM($A$1:$D$10;"Number";$I$16:$K$19)
I cannot obtain the correct sum (25) of the yew trees because the function calculate 108.
Then with the same database and the following array



Plant
Field
Expire Date




Oak
B
>=2026-04-24


Maple
A
<=2031-10-22


Cherry




Elm




Pine





I try to to get the sum of the Oak, Maple, Cherry, Elm and Pine trees, in the fields A and B, with a maturity between >=2026-04-24 to <=2031-10-22 with this function:
DSUM($A$1:$D$10;"Number";$I$8:$K$13)
and the obtained result is 68 while only 10 trees meet the requirements.
Just in case it is more convenient  for a visual approach,
In the following link, I reported in the yellow box these two DSUM functions and one more that function correctly.
example database where I show the mistakes

I want to clarify, if your expected answer to this should be using DSUM or are you open to another set of formula.


I cannot obtain the correct sum (25) of the yew trees because the function calculate 108.

When there's an empty value in the `criteria` array, the function doesn't impose any restriction on the filtering. This means that a row of empty values matches the whole database, that's why you get 108 for the sum. (Ref. Database functions)
The correct way to do this is by changing the third table to:



Plant
Field
Expire Date




Yew
A
<=2034-10-22


Yew
B
<=2034-10-22



And restricting the range in `criteria` to the non-empty rows:
=DSUM(A1:D10;"Number";I16:K18)


But a better solution would be to change the table to:



Plant
Field
Expire Date




Yew

<=2034-10-22



And restrict the `criteria` range to the first row:
=DSUM(A1:D10;"Number";I16:K17)


You could also use SUMIFS:
=SUMIFS(B2:B10;A2:A10;I17;D2:D10;K17)


Use QUERY() function.
=QUERY(A2:D10;"select sum(B) where A matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|";1;I9:I13)&"' and C matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|";1;J9:J13)&"' and D>= date '" & TEXT(G3;"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' and D<= date '" & TEXT(G4;"yyyy-mm-dd")& "'")


